# Installing Sitecore Package deletes content

Tags: sitecore-client, package-designer

When installing a package with overwrite option, some items are being automatically deleted where the package is installed.

Will installing a package with overwrite option delete content items?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `override` option while installing a package, it replaces every item and its descendants with items from the package.

So if you have item `A` in your application and it has 2 children `A1` and `A2`, and your package contains item with same ID as item `A`, after your package is installed, you will have only what is in your package and old items `A`, `A1` and `A2` will be removed.

If you want Sitecore to leave old items, try using `merge` options.

You can read more e.g. here: [SITECORE PACKAGE INSTALLATION OPTIONS EXPLAINED](http://www.partech.nl/nl/blog/2012/11/sitecore-package-installation-options-explained)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marek. But the overwrite option surely not gonna delete the items from the tree. It will replace the old one with new one right?

Comment: But recently I tried to replace only one item in the tree and check the overwrite option, and also clicked on the Apply to All button and it results the deletion of all the items in the tree.
 Do you know why?

Please Suggest

Comment: If the item from the package has no children but the original item had children, the children of the original item will be removed.

Comment: Thanks Marek.
I created a package for subitem only which has no further subitems and override when installing the package, then other subitems will get deleted.
why so?

Comment: It's how Sitecore behaves when you choose "override" option. Official documentation says: "Items with the same ID (along with any existing children) are replaced by items from the package." (see https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/package_designer_admin_guide-usletter.pdf )

Comment: @Agent47 If you create the package with only subitems (as you mention in your earlier comment), and choose orverride when installing, it should not delete other subimtes that does not included in the package.